# Java 1.6 Maven project with SOAP XML JAX-WS ( WAS Portal 7 ) services to Tomcat Liferay 6.2 GA6 can´t access endpoint

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jax-ws, liferay-6

i'm trying to understand what am i missing here...need some pointers from you guys.
So previously i had been developing in a legacy system in a Maven Java 1.6 Project supported by IBM WAS ( Websphere Aplication Server ) Portal 7. I did not start this project so my knowledge about this is limited and this project had/have a working JAX-WS ( SOAP/XML ) services, that were generated or manually made ( don´t know ) (Fig1). Where the implementation of that Web services Interface is like this ( Fig2. ).

In this Portal if i do this URL the XML Schema apears like Fig3:

This is to explain 1st part ( please do comment if i need to show more things for you to help me ). Second part after pictures. BTW my IDE is Eclipse Oxygen with Tomcat App.Server.

**Fig1**
[image]

**Fig2**
[image]

**Fig3**
[image]

So the same project same WAR file was migrated to Liferay 6.2 GA6 supported by Tomcat ( 7 )  but these WS stopped working or are not even exposed properly, if i type the same URL changing only the liferay URL to the same end point like so [ **LIFERAYURL_MACHINE/PROJECT_NAME/InternetUser/InternetUser.wsdl** ] , liferay says cannot find obviously.

So i have been searching the web about this and i found out that liferay has its own exposed webservices in this URL [ **http://MACHINE:PORT/api/axis** ] like you can see in Fig4. If i press in one of does links i get the wsdl in following URL [ http://MACHINE:8780/api/axis/Portlet_Bookmarks_BookmarksEntryService?wsdl ]

Fig4
[image]

**THE QUESTION UFFFFF:**
So i'm very "rookie" to liferay and i'm in need off some pointers on what do i need to focuse in, where do i need to go, to search etc.. regarding exposing these already made webservices.
Do i need to recreate them? Using Liferay tools, do i need a propertie of some kind ? Also i have this Fig5, Fig6. if its any help at all.

Note: This project is running on a portlet for liferay.

**Fig5.**
[image]

**Fig6.**
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code/text as images.

Comment: @OlafKock Images were just to explain my point of view and not for people to help me specifically in the code. Because that i know. Thank you for the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're expecting your (manually implemented) Webservices in Liferay's list of published WSDLs. I've never tried this, and could well imagine that this is not the way that Liferay picks up those endpoints.

A safe way to implement these Webservices if you expect them to show up in Liferay's list of provided webservices is to use Liferay's ServiceBuilder, which will provide you with a couple of default features - among them being listed in the list of available WSDLs.

Comment: well that's it, but its not required they show up in that endpoint. But after reading some articles, i think i understood that Liferay is like a shell that exposes does WSDL's by default to the outside world, so i was trying to do the same with my projects implementation.

You typed Liferay's ServiceBuilder and i have stumble in that aswell but couldn´t understand how can i connect what i already have with that, in terms of code...

Answer (score 0):

```
To expose a JAX-WS web-service in Liferay I use WSServlet.
In web.xml put:
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet&lt;/servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebService&lt;/servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CoreService17&lt;/url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener&lt;/listener-class>
</listener>

There must be sun-jaxws.xml file near web.xml that contains:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/sun-jaxws.xsd ">
    <endpoint  implementation="ru.isands.tyva_portlet.web_service.CorePortType17Impl" name="CoreService17" url-pattern="/CoreService17"/>
</endpoints>

Class ru.isands.tyva_portlet.web_service.CorePortType17Impl implements WebService interface :
@WebService(name = "CorePortType17", targetNamespace = "urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/poltava/core/1.7", serviceName = "CoreService17", portName = "CoreEndpoint17")
@HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")
@XmlSeeAlso({ org.w3._2004._08.xop.include.ObjectFactory.class })
public class CorePortType17Impl implements CorePortType17 {
...
}

CorePortType17.java:
@WebService(name = "CorePortType17", targetNamespace = "urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/poltava/core/1.7")
public interface CorePortType17 {
...
}
```

My handler-chain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <handler-chain>
    <handler>
      <handler-name>SigningSoapHandler</handler-name>
      <handler-class>ru.isands.tyva_portlet.web_service.SigningSoapHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
  </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>

public class SigningSoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {...}
```

Comment: can you please add handler-chain.xml aswell please ? And thank you for your help i'll try this ASP. ;)

Comment: Hi have you tried this aproach in Liferay 7.3 ?

Comment: No, I stopped working with Liferay.